# Why is movement in this program still coupled to the emission of keydown events?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard

A red square is added as a DOM node and wired to the arrow keys on the keyboard.

My own keyboard handling logic tries to circumvent delays and easing related to the emission of `keydown` events. The square should move immediately at full speed when an arrow key is pressed.

But the movement of the square still follows the emission of the keydown events.

Why is this?

The way this code works is:

- a `keyPresses` object that maintains a list of key presses for each arrow keycode with their duration
- the length of these lists will usually be zero or one because,
- the list is reset every animation frame
- by relying on `requestAnimationFrame` I had hoped to be able to stop relying on keydown events
- `37`, `38`, `39`, `40` magic numbers are the keycodes for the arrow keys

```js
const ROOT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');
const PLAYER_NODE = document.createElement('div');
const createKeyPressStore = () => ({ 37: [], 38: [], 39: [], 40: [] });

const plus = (a, b) => a + b;
const minus = (a, b) => a - b;
const isArrow = ({ keyCode }) => [37, 38, 39, 40].includes(keyCode);
const translate = (axis, transform) => ([x, y], translation) =>
  axis === 'x' ? [transform(x, translation), y] : [x, transform(y, translation)];
const normalise = (n, normal) => (n < normal ? normal : n);
const distance = (duration, velocity) => ~~(normalise(duration, 16) / 16 * velocity);
const moveMap = {
  37: translate('x', minus),
  38: translate('y', minus),
  39: translate('x', plus),
  40: translate('y', plus)
};
const calcLeft = ({ style: { left } }, [x]) => +left.substr(0, left.length - 2) + x;
const calcTop = ({ style: { top } }, [_, y]) => +top.substr(0, top.length - 2) + y;
const resetKeyPresses = store => ((store.keyPresses = createKeyPressStore()), store);
const now = () => ~~performance.now();
const createStore = () => ({
  rootNode: ROOT_NODE,
  player: { node: PLAYER_NODE, velocity: 10 },
  keyPresses: createKeyPressStore()
});

const onkeydown = ({ keyPresses }, e) => (
  isArrow(e) && (keyPresses[e.keyCode][0] && !keyPresses[e.keyCode][0].stop && (keyPresses[e.keyCode][0].stop = now())),
  keyPresses[e.keyCode].unshift({ start: now() }),
  false
);

const onkeyup = ({ keyPresses }, e) =>
  isArrow(e) && keyPresses[e.keyCode][0] && (keyPresses[e.keyCode][0].stop = now());

const calcTranslation = (store, result = [0, 0]) => (
  (result = Object.entries(store.keyPresses).reduce(
    (p, [key, list]) =>
      list.reduce(
        (p1, { start, stop }) => (
          (stop = stop || start), moveMap[key](p1, distance(stop - start, store.player.velocity))
        ),
        p
      ),
    result
  )),
  (store.keyPresses = createKeyPressStore()),
  result
);

const draw = (store, translation = calcTranslation(store), node = store.player.node) => (
  (node.style.left = `${calcLeft(node, translation)}px`),
  (node.style.top = `${calcTop(node, translation)}px`),
  resetKeyPresses(store)
);

const listenForEvents = store => (
  ((window.document.onkeydown = e => onkeydown(store, e)), (window.document.onkeyup = e => onkeyup(store, e))), store
);

const initDOM = store => (
  store.player.node.setAttribute('id', 'player'), store.rootNode.appendChild(store.player.node), store
);

const go = store => (draw(store), requestAnimationFrame(() => go(store)));

go(listenForEvents(initDOM(createStore())));
```

```css
#root { 
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

#player { 
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body id="root">

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey man,, I'm pretty sure you can't change default keyboard delay(lot of OS stuff here), but I'd rather implement some acceleraion variable * time to move the dot faster (if that's your goal)

Comment: Instead of relying on the built-in auto-repeat, set your own timer during the first keydown, and clear it when you get the keyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the answer. The issue is that in-progress presses are effectively cancelled by this code each animation frame.

The following code solves the issue.

```js
const ROOT_NODE = document.getElementById('root');
const PLAYER_NODE = document.createElement('div');
const createKeyPressStore = () => ({ 37: [], 38: [], 39: [], 40: [] });

const plus = (a, b) => a + b;
const minus = (a, b) => a - b;
const isArrow = ({ keyCode }) => [37, 38, 39, 40].includes(keyCode);
const translate = (axis, transform) => ([x, y], translation) =>
  axis === 'x' ? [transform(x, translation), y] : [x, transform(y, translation)];
const normalise = (n, normal) => (n < normal ? normal : n);
const distance = (duration, velocity) => ~~(normalise(duration, 16) / 16 * velocity);
const moveMap = {
  37: translate('x', minus),
  38: translate('y', minus),
  39: translate('x', plus),
  40: translate('y', plus)
};
const calcLeft = ({ style: { left } }, [x]) => +left.substr(0, left.length - 2) + x;
const calcTop = ({ style: { top } }, [_, y]) => +top.substr(0, top.length - 2) + y;
const resetKeyPresses = store => ((store.keyPresses = createKeyPressStore()), store);
const now = () => ~~performance.now();
const createStore = () => ({
  rootNode: ROOT_NODE,
  player: { node: PLAYER_NODE, velocity: 2 },
  keyPresses: createKeyPressStore()
});

const onkeydown = ({ keyPresses }, e) => (
  isArrow(e) && (keyPresses[e.keyCode][0] && !keyPresses[e.keyCode][0].stop && (keyPresses[e.keyCode][0].stop = now())),
  keyPresses[e.keyCode].unshift({ start: now() }),
  false
);

const onkeyup = ({ keyPresses }, e) =>
  isArrow(e) && keyPresses[e.keyCode][0] && (keyPresses[e.keyCode][0].stop = now());

const calcTranslation = (store, result = [0, 0], inProgress = createKeyPressStore()) => (
  (result = Object.entries(store.keyPresses).reduce(
    (p, [key, list]) =>
      list.reduce(
        (p1, { start, stop }) => (
          !stop && start && inProgress[key].unshift({ start: now() }),
          moveMap[key](p1, distance((stop || start) - start, store.player.velocity))
        ),
        p
      ),
    result
  )),
  (store.keyPresses = inProgress),
  result
);

const draw = (store, translation = calcTranslation(store), node = store.player.node) => (
  (node.style.left = `${calcLeft(node, translation)}px`),
  (node.style.top = `${calcTop(node, translation)}px`)
);

const listenForEvents = store => (
  ((window.document.onkeydown = e => onkeydown(store, e)), (window.document.onkeyup = e => onkeyup(store, e))), store
);

const initDOM = store => (
  store.player.node.setAttribute('id', 'player'), store.rootNode.appendChild(store.player.node), store
);

const go = store => (draw(store), requestAnimationFrame(() => go(store)));

go(listenForEvents(initDOM(createStore())));
```

```css
#root { 
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

#player { 
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body id="root">

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```